# 3G for GPS Connection

Tags: android, gps

I like to clarify, is `3G connection` needed to get the `GPS location`? Also currently is it possible to `geotag` pictures taken through the native camera under settings.

But I could not find such a setting for videos. Is `geotagging` for videos supported in Android?

Thanks In Advance,
Perumal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is 3G connection needed to get the GPS location?

No, but it helps. What you are thinking about is Assisted GPS. Here the satellite position and other information is downloaded from some SUPL servers. GPS will work on most Android devices without assistance, though it may take longer.

> Geotagging for videos supported in Android?

No, if you see the media containers that the video is stored in, there is no support for Video geo-tagging. Android keeps track of the location of the video, in an internal database.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Now if I want to geotag my video, is it possible by using the Android's ExifInterface class?

Comment: No, that is only for images. For Videos, as far as I know, right now, only Apple media containers support it, for e.g. mov and mkv.

Answer (score 1):

OK, couple of questions combined in one.. let me try to answer them separately.

- **3G connection needed to get the GPS location?**

  No you don't need 3G/2G (Internet) connection for Geo Point using GPS, but yes you need it for Obtaining Geo point using Network Location. (There are 2 options if you see in your settings.

  1. Network Location
  2. GPS Location
- **Geotag pictures taken through the native camera under settings**

  Do you wish to know the Native Android Camera capabilities? In that case yes you need to enable the geo tagging under your camera settings, usually pointed as a big dot.
  In case you are taking image by yourself (invoking camera from your application) then you are expected to manage the tagging yourself.
- **Geotagging for videos supported in Android?**

  The geo tagging feature for video is not available in Native Camera Application. (I guess its very appropriate to think that the user is going to be at one place only while taking a video.)

Answer (score 0):

1. No you don't need a 3G connection for get the GPS locations
2. You may need a Internet connection (GPRS, 3G, WiFi, etc) for get the maps and represent the GPS information.
3. When you ask for video geotaging. Are you asking as User or Programmer?